# jquery datepicker - compare months of two dates

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, date, if-statement

I am trying to compare the months of two dates using the jquery datepicker. I want it to check and see if my end date has the same month as my start date so that I can add in the end date month if needed:

Instead of displaying:

**Event Dates**

January 1st - 1st, 2017

March 3rd - 4th, 2017

I want to display:

**Event Dates**

January 1st - *February* 1st, 2017

March 3rd - 4th, 2017

This is the code I have so far. PS. I am using advanced custom fields within wordpress. That is why get_field('event_start_date') pulls in the date. The only argument I really need help with is the `<?php if ($endDate[M] != $startDate[M]): ?>` code. That was just my best guess on how to do this but it does not work at all.

```
            <p>
              <?php if( get_field('event_start_date') ): ?>
                 <?php $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_start_date')); ?>
                 <?php echo $startDate->format('F'); ?> <?php echo $startDate->format('jS'); ?> 
                    <?php if( get_field('event_end_date') ): ?>
                        <?php $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_end_date')); ?>
                                                     - 
                        <?php if ($endDate[M] != $startDate[M]): ?>
                            <?php echo $endDate->format('F'); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo $endDate->format('jS'); ?>, <?php echo $endDate->format('Y'); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        , <?php echo $startDate->format('Y'); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
```

Comment: you want to add month to end date if same with start date. but why are you still want `March 3rd - 4th, 2017` as `March 3rd - 4th, 2017`

Comment: @WhoAmI I want to only list the end date's month if it is different from the start dates month. It's a design preference.